# Insertion of characters in strings in R

Tags: regex, r

I would like to insert "`&`" between letters (upper-case and lower-case), but not before or after letters, and replace each lower-case letter `x` by `tt$X==0`, each upper-case letter `X` by `tt$X==1`, and each `+` by `)|(`, plus an opening bracket and a closing bracket around the entire string, so as to get an expression that can be evaluated in R. For example, I have the string

```
st <- "AbC + de + FGHIJ"
```

The result should then look like this:

```
"(tt$A==1 & tt$B==0 & tt$C==1) | (tt$D==0 & tt$E==0) | (tt$F==1 & tt$G==1 & tt$H==1 & tt$I==1 & tt$J==1)"
```

Could I easily do this with the `gsub()` function?

Comment: This looks like an issue that would not even arise if you weren't trying to evaluate text as an expression. What is the root issue that is being solved here?

Comment: The first observation is undoubtedly very true. The answer to the question is that I need to index matrices/data frames in accordance with Boolean expressions that are present as strings of the form in `st`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A bunch of regexps are rarely elegant, and often hard to debug. The above regexp solution fails if there's not that exact spacing between elements.

```
> tt("aBc+b")
[1] "(tt$A==0 & tt$B==1 & tt$C==0+tt$B==0)"
> tt("aBc + b")
[1] "(tt$A==0 & tt$B==1 & tt$C==0) | (tt$B==0)"
```

Sometimes you just have to split the bits up yourself and process them. Here's a solution:

```
doChar = Vectorize(
    function(c){
        sprintf("tt$%s==%s",toupper(c),ifelse(c %in% LETTERS,"1","0"))
    }
)

doWord = Vectorize(function(W){
    cs = strsplit(W,"")[[1]]
    paste0("(",
           paste(doChar(cs),collapse=" & "),
           ")")
})

processString = function(st){
    parts = strsplit(st,"\\+")[[1]]
    parts = gsub(" ","",parts)
    paste0(doWord(parts),collapse=" | ")
}
```

There's probably many ways to make it better, but it has the benefit of being a bit easier to debug (you can test the parts) and looks less like line noise :)

For the sample string given it returns the same as the `tt` function which is my function wrapper of the regexp solution:

```
> tt(st)==processString(st)
[1] TRUE
```

But handles spacing:

```
> processString("aBc + deF") == processString("aBc+deF")
[1] TRUE
```

Its always a good idea to write code that is a bit flexible in the inputs it accepts. You might also notice that the `tt` part of the output elements appears only once, so if you want to output `foo$A` instead of `tt$A` there's only one change needed. The regexp solution has this in three places (or maybe four if I've missed one!).

Comment: Great solution, many thanks! I'll try to improve it further if possible, but I can't see how at the moment.

Comment: How can you say that your solution looks less like line noise when your solution is literally 3x more lines of code than mine? Your solution runs the user through three different functions just to get the solution and your `ifelse` statement in the `doChar` isn't even immediately intuitive. You throw a lot of jabs in your post for someone who answered 4 days after an accepted solution had been posted with a code that's three times as long. Handling the spaces between `+` and replacing `tt` with some other word are easily handled in a more succinct way.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this, but it's not very elegant

```
st <- "AbC + de + FGHIJ"
t1 <- gsub("([a-z])", "tt\\$\\U\\1==0", st, perl = TRUE)
t2 <- gsub("((?<!\\$)[A-Z])", "tt\\$\\U\\1==1", t1, perl = TRUE)
t3 <- gsub("([0-9])(tt)", "\\1 & \\2", t2)
t4 <- gsub(" + ", ") | (", t3, fixed = TRUE)
t5 <- paste("(", t4, ")", sep = "")

st
# "AbC + de + FGHIJ"
t5
# "(tt$A==1 & tt$B==0 & tt$C==1) | (tt$D==0 & tt$E==0) | (tt$F==1 & tt$G==1 & tt$H==1 & tt$I==1 & tt$J==1)"
```

Here's an explanation of what it does:

t1 replaces all lower case letters with `tt$X==0` where `X` is the uppercase letter that was replaced. The uppercase letter is produced with `\\U\\1` where `\\U` generates the uppercase and `\\1` returns the first capture group. Capture groups are what are caught inside parentheses.

Now that the lowercase letters are out of the way (necessary to do first so that we don't replace `tt`), we replace capital letters, but only if they're preceded by a `$`. To tell `gsub` to ignore capital letters after a dollar sign, we use the negative lookbehind `(?<!)` and the `\\$` tells it to ignore a dollar sign. We then again replace our letter with the uppercase letter we're replacing.

Next, we need to insert a space between all of the letters we replaced. The best way to do that is to just acknowledge that `tt$` will be preceded by a digit everytime a space is needed. So we look for a digit followed by "tt" and replace it with the first capture group, " & ", followed by the second capture group.

Then we need to replace the "+" symbols. So we replace that and the whitespace around it with ") | (". We used `fixed = TRUE` to avoid needing to escape the parentheses and the OR operator.

Lastly, we append the leading and trailing parentheses to give us a fully functioning conditional phrase.

### Edit

Per the comments made in the other solution, we can make a couple changes to my proposed solution to a) make it more robust, and b) more flexible. To make it more robust, we simply change `t4` so that it is now:

`t4 <- gsub(" ?\\+ ?", ") | (", t3)`

We simply add question marks after the spaces to say that there can be 0 or 1, escape the `+`, and remove `fixed = TRUE`. We have to remove `fixed = TRUE` because we need the regex functions to test for a space or not.

To make it more flexible, we simply wrap it in a function that allows us to pass the string and our desired object name.

```
parse_string <- function(string, object_name) {
  st <- string
  t1 <- gsub("([a-z])", paste0(object_name, "\\$\\U\\1==0"), st, perl = TRUE)
  t2 <- gsub("((?<!\\$)[A-Z])", paste0(object_name, "\\$\\U\\1==1"), t1, perl = TRUE)
  t3 <- gsub(paste0("([0-9])(", object_name, ")"), "\\1 & \\2", t2)
  t4 <- gsub(" ?\\+ ?", ") | (", t3)
  t5 <- paste("(", t4, ")", sep = "")
  return(t5)
}

> parse_string(st, "tt") == t5
# [1] TRUE
> parse_string(st, "foo")
# [1] "(foo$A==1 & foo$B==0 & foo$C==1) | (foo$D==0 & foo$E==0) | (foo$F==1 & foo$G==1 & foo$H==1 & foo$I==1 & foo$J==1)"
> parse_string("AbC+de+FGHIJ", "tt") == t5
# [1] TRUE
```

Comment: Many thanks for this very useful answer (I think it's quite elegant)! And the explanation was great!

Comment: By the way, in this relation, why does `gsub("([a-zA-Z])([a-zA-Z])", "\\1&\\2", st)` not put an ampersand between all single letters but only the first and second, third and fourth, etc.? How could I place the ampersand between all single letters? `gsub("([a-zA-Z])([a-zA-Z](?!\\+))", "\\1&\\2&", st, perl = TRUE)` does the job but now prevents `&` being put between a first and a second single letter if there are only two consecutive single letters. (sorry for these probably basic questions, but I'm new to regular expressions)

Comment: This is actually a really good question, and I'm not sure why that's the case. I think it definitely warrants a follow up.

Comment: So I asked the question on SO and got the answer. Essentially, regex won't "reuse" matches. So in your first approach, the regex matches "Ab" and replaces it with "A & b". When it continues, it realizes that it's already matched the "b" and so it skips it moving to "C ". Since "C" is followed by a space, it doesn't match the regex and therefore no substitution is made. That's why it's only replacing the letters at seemingly odd intervals. Hope that helps clear it up.